# Spring Boot, Hibernate JPA - Why is it creating two tables for each entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I've run into some strange behaviour.

I had this code working fine on a Windows machine, but when I run it on Linux, it no longer works.

I am using spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE and an in-memory H2 database.

When I run my application, I can see that it is creating tables, but for some reason, it creates each one twice.

```
o.h.t.s.e.i.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: image
o.h.t.s.e.i.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: image
o.h.t.s.e.i.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: image_tags
o.h.t.s.e.i.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: image_tags
```

The database then has two tables for each entity (for example, for an entity called "MyTable", it will create "mytable" and "my_table"

I don't even know where to start with fixing this. (I'm starting to think that spring-boot is a bit flakey and I should just go back to an old-fashion web app - I used to understand them better!)

I had a problem before with Hibernate creating table names with underscores in and fixed it by using the EJB naming strategy, but I have no idea why it is not working now.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Here is one of the entity classes, nothing magical going on here. This would result in two tables being created, "userconnection" and "user_connection"

```
@Entity(name = "UserConnection")
@IdClass(UserConnectionKey.class)
public class UserConnection extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "providerId")
    private String providerId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "providerUserId")
    private String providerUserId;
    @Column(name = "rank")
    private int rank;
    @Column(name = "displayName")
    private String displayName;
    @Column(name = "profileUrl")
    private String profileUrl;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(name = "accessToken")
    private String accessToken;
    @Column(name = "secret")
    private String secret;
    @Column(name = "refreshToken")
    private String refreshToken;
    @Column(name = "expireTime")
    private Long expireTime;

    ... getters + setters ....
```

**** UPDATE

I found the problem.

I had updated the spring boot version to 1.4.0 on the version that does not work. I did this because I had installed gradle 3 and the 1.3.5 spring boot plug-in did not work with it.

I've now installed gradle 2.14.1 and gone back to spring boot 1.3.5. Now I only get the tables I want (i.e. one set of tables without underscores in the name)

It looks like it is because a different version of hibernate.

How annoying...

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Why is this a problem? The log you posted doesn't show anything I'd be concerned about.

Comment: @chrylis The strange thing is it says "table not found" twice for each entity, then it has created two tables, i.e. "MY_TABLE" and "mytable"

Comment: Need to see your entity classes, then.

Comment: (Note that as a general matter, Boot will disable any configuration you supply yourself. If you had some pre-existing Hibernate setup that did exactly what you wanted, you should be able to drop it in and override the defaults.)

Comment: The JPA spec would imply a table of name "USERCONNECTION" (with no underscore, but possibly different case depending on datastore), and that is the way for portability. The other one is bogus.